# How can I fetch the latest log file to scrape every time I run my python script?

Tags: python-2.7

There is a list of json logs in my Downloads folder.
Every time I run this script I want the latest one to be fetched.

```
import json

json_file = '/home/Downloads/log12-41-12.json'
json_data = open(json_file)
logs = json.load(json_data)

for index in logs:
    print(index)

file.close()
json_data.close()
```

Comment: Note, there is a code sample button you can use to format your code.

Comment: How is "the latest one" defined?

Comment: The file gets saved with timestamp. How to compare two timestamps in the file name before parsing it?

Comment: Does 12-41-12 mean 12h 41m 12s in 24 hour clock? If so what exactly the format is hh-mm-ss or ss-mm-hh?

Answer (score 1):

Code Snippet

```
 import os
 logdir='/home/Downloads/' # path to your log directory
 logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if.startswith('log')])
 print "Most recent file = %s" % (logfiles[-1],)
```

Comment: 1. I'd use `max` instead of `sorted`: It's faster. 2. I'd also use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension: lover memory requirements.